# Git pull removes symlink

Tags: git

You'll have to excuse me if this is a duplicate, there are a lot of questions relating to this but they are describing a different scenario.

I am trying to use a file from a repo that I have forked in a **different** git project. In order to be able to update both repos at the same time I'm using a symlink.

```
ln -s path/to/public/library/file.py path/to/my/project/file.py
```

This works fine for the most part, when I change the file in my project they are reflected in the library repo. But when I do a `git pull` in the library repo, the symlink in my project repo gets destroyed.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I do not want to have to recreate the symlink every time I do a pull in the library repo.

I am using a raspberry pi. The OS is Raspbian Jessie (based off of Debian Linux). I am using git version 2.1.4 and through the CLI.

Comment: I have seen similar questions in the past, but I have been unable to reproduce. My symlinks are preserved between repositories on push and pull. It might be pertinent to include your environment conditions such as OS, git version, and whether you're using a git GUI application or straight CLI

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I updated the question with that info.